# Is there a better way to check multiple optionals and combine the results with OR?

Tags: swift, swift3

Let's say I have two optionals and I want to run some logic when at least one of optionals has value.
I have following code at this moment, but I feel there must be better way to do that...

```
if let A = optionalA {
    doSomething()
    return
}

if let B = optionalB {
    doSomething()
    return
}
```

Comment: You can't combine optional binding with OR, but you could check `if optionalA != nil || optionalB != nil {`.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using flatMap and check the count :)

Comment: Seems like a complicated way to do it, but yeah, that would work.